# How to add quantifiers to group in a pattern in VIM?

Tags: regular-expression

I am trying to highlight a set of lines, between the line containing ULS at the top of the line, to the line containing star in the bottom. I have tried many combination but I have failed. If someone could kindly guide me the correct regex for that selection. (Note: I am working in Windows).

I have unsuccessfully tried to use the following regex:

```
/ULS\p\+\n\(\n\p\+\{-\}\)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear about precisely what you're trying to achieve, but this search finds the lines between ULS and the first line that follows that begins with a "*" character, and includes all the lines *between* those lines within a capture group:

```
/ULS\p\+\n\(\_p\{-}\)\n\*
```

Broken down:

- `/ULS`: "ULS"
- `\p\+\n`: Any number of printable characters, followed by a newline
- `\(`: Start of capture group
- `\_p\{-}`: Any number of printable characters, including newlines. `\_p` is a variant of `\p` that also matches newlines (the underscore can be used in other character classes in the same way: see `:help 27.8` for details). `\{-}` is a non-greedy version of `*`
- `\)`: End of capture group
- `\n\*`: A newline followed by a star.

Comment: Thank you Rich this is exactly what I was looking for. Additionally could you point me to some resource which could help me improve my understanding of regex.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd recommend it as the best tutorial, but most of what I know about regular expressions I learned from reading through `:help regexp`. `:help usr_27` is a much more readable introduction, though.